# Why do I need sudo to reboot from the command line?

Tags: sudo, reboot, dbus

When I enter `reboot` on the command line, I get:

```
reboot: Need to be root
```

and asked the root / sudo password. When I reboot via the gui I can do that without my sudo password. Why is that? What's happening internally of the ubuntu system there?